# Toggle the touch and hold setting on tablet-pc

Tags: touch, registry, right-click, delphi-xe6

I'm trying to find a way to enable/disable the touch-and-hold setting for a tablet-pc with immediate effect (no reboot).

I'm creating a delphi application where you can draw a shape by pressing and holding for a set amount of time (immediate swiping is used for panning). The problem is that a press and hold is often used to trigger a right-click event intitiated by a square or circle animation around your finger while holding. The only way I've been successful in hiding this animation/right-click behaviour is by completely disabling the touch-and-hold setting in the configuration screen or in the registry (which needs a reboot.. ).

Now how would I disable this right-click behaviour when my application is focused, but set it back to the default setting when losing focus?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Why don't you preprocess the long press event, or something like that? I'm not familiar with delphi but this would be fairly simple in c#. You could add a handler for the `context menu opening` event or implement a custom tap and hold controls with a timer and down/up handlers for touch or mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is after windows 10 build updated to 14986.  It is not allowed to disable/uninstall HID-compliant touch screen that BLUE SCREEN as disable/uninstall.

It works to disable touch screen as I changed the following registries :
\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Wisp\Touch
1. [Bouncing] change value to [0]
2. [Inertia]  change value to [0]
3. [TouchMode_hold] change value to [0]
4. [TouchUI] change value to [0]

Hope it works to you 2.

Comment: I am currently working on windows 7. The problem isn't changing the registry, rather it's making the settings apply without a reboot. In the same manner that you get when you change the touch settings through the configuration screen.